# What does the `/l` mean in the mode `C++/l` mean?

Tags: major-mode, c++

Just a simple question with more than likely a simple answer:

What does the `/l` mean in the mode `C++/l` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indicates that you are using the electric indentation feature. The different minor modes, and their flags, are explained in the manual: `(info "(ccmode) Minor Modes")`. You can also get there by `C-h i m cc <RET> m min <RET>`.

I didn't memorize that last command, it's mostly autocompleted:

- `C-h i` opens the info system
- `m` prompts for a menu item
- `cc` selects the CC-mode menu item
- `m` prompts for a menu item in the CC-mode man page
- `min` selects the `min`or modes man page